# Vim delete/yank/copy a key/entry block from JSON or javascript object

Tags: vim

I work with a lot of JSON. It's super common that I'll want to operate on an entire block of JSON--Selecting an entire block, deleting the block, moving it, etc. Is there any way to operate on the key and its value combined?

Mockup:

[image: vim delete json key mockup]

A motion like `viB` won't work in this case because it will select all the children in the same nest level (not what I want). I want the complete block and only that block for whatever the cursor is over.

Comment: `bv%l` or `V%`, beyond that you'll almost certainly have to make your own script unless there's a plugin for it.

Comment: If it's formatted that way, `V%d` should do the job.

Comment: Those work in visual, is there no equivalent normal operator?

Answer (score 3):

Using [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) you can define a textobject to select whatever you want. Here is one to select a block matching your criteria that I just wrote:

```
call textobj#user#plugin('textobj-syntax-is-garbage', {
\   'regex_j': {
\     'select': 'aj',
\     '*pattern*': '^\s*"\?\w\+"\?\s*:\s*{\_[^}]*}.*\n\?',
\   })
```

This will *not* work for nested json blocks :( but it will work for your use case

The `aj` means you can execute <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> or whatever your little heart desires.

Explanation:

`^\s*"\?\w\+"\?\s*:\s*{`

Match from the start of the line to a key (word characters) with optional double quotes

`\_[^}]*`

Match anything that's not a closing nipple bracket. `\_` means match across multiple lines.

`}.*\n\?`

Match a closing nipple bracket, and an optional newline so that it will not leave a line break around after you delete the block.

This regex could definietly be improved. It's probably impossible to do correct nested block selection with a regex, but I think textobj-entire lets you specify a function to run as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a plugin that works on arguments/parameters called [Argumentative](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3933). Argumentative provides a new text objects, `i,` and `a,`. You can also shift arguments via `>,` and `<,`. I am sure there are other plugins out there that do similar things.